# Why isn't working null pointer check for C style string?

Tags: c++, nullptr

This is my function:

```
void printCString(char *s)
{
    while (s != nullptr) // printing doesn't stop after ! from passed string.
    {
        std::cout << *s;
        ++s;
    }
}
```

and I call it:

```
char s[]{ "Hello, world!" };
printCString(s);
```

If I replace stop condition from `while` block with:

```
while (*s != '\0')
```

than it's working well. Can anybody explain me why this behavior?

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? While traversing a C-style string you'll eventually find a zero character, but the pointer you use for traversal has no reason to become null.

Comment: `s` points somewhere in memory. You are checking whether `s` points to memory location zero (more or less). There's no reason why the next memory location after the `!` of the string should be memory location zero.

Comment: You basically expect s to point to nullptr when you reach the 15th iteration, but you don't know what's in there (undefined) because this memory is not part of s.

Comment: I got it now. I mixed `nullptr` for null character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s` is never `nullptr`, since `nullptr` is unattainable via pointer arithmetic.

Conceptually you'd need to *deference* `s`, but `*s != nullptr` will not compile. That's no bad thing since there is no guarantee that `nullptr` is the same as the C-style string terminator `NUL`.

Comment: `*s != nullptr` shouldn't compile.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: Indeed (although I did once use a compiler that allowed it ;-) )

Comment: regarding "nullptr is unattainable via pointer arithmetic.":
    while (ptr) ptr--; 
will give you nullptr (https://godbolt.org/z/EX9GNo)

Comment: @olivecoder: No, that's undefined behaviour. Pointer arithmetic is only valid within arrays.

Comment: is UB the same as "unattainable " and "s is never nullptr" ?

Comment: @olivecoder: Broadly yes. A compiler is allowed to assume that `while (s != nullptr)` will never terminate. This is a dark area of the C++ standard, might be worth your asking a question on this.

Comment: I did once use a compiler that allowed it

Comment: @olivecoder: Yup, I use one that allows it too. But on other occasions a compiler might optimise away the loop, or eat your cat.

Comment: Actually I dont know a compiler that doens't allow that but my actual point is: the first line of your response is misleading and I'm downvoting it because we refuse to recognize that and fix it. The code isn't failing because 's is never nullptr'.

Comment: @olivecoder No, `nullptr` is not attainable via pointer arithmetic. That `gcc` compiles your code (which has undefined behavior) to `return 0;` is absolutely not proof of your theory - you can't prove that a program is valid/UB-free by showing how a compiler accepts it. And for the record, `clang` will turn it into an endless loop (which, btw, is also UB): https://godbolt.org/z/Rm5HEh How do you explain that?

Comment: @olivecoder: That's an odd rationale. The behaviour is undefined. `s` is never `nullptr` is the correct thing to say.

Comment: It is UB, I didn't say the opposite. But `s` isn't going to be `nullptr` not because of the UB but because of deferencing the invalid pointer in the loop and that is what he is gonna see in the backtrace when debugging that code. The code isn't working because he is not deferencing `s` when checking for the end of the string, actually. Yes, he invoked UB when making his mistake but that is secondary as he doesn't actually want to check if `s` is `nullptr`.